# Can you tell me, who am I?

Tags: riddle

Let me describe you someone or somewhat

> If he stands alone, he is one of the biggest around.
>
> Only the guy at first place,  may be as big as he is.
>
> Surrounded by others of his kind, he gets as small as they are or even smaller.
>
> Stepping other countries, he can't even hold his size except he starts out first.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling.SE, Comann! Do take a look at the [tour](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tour) page as well.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I believe the answer is

> The letter "i"

If he stands alone, he is one of the biggest around.

> The word "I" is always capitalized

Only the guy at first place, may be as big as he is.

> Only the first letter in the sentence may also be capitalized. (Let's ignore proper nouns)

Surrounded by others of his kind, he gets as small as they are or even smaller.

> When "i" is part of a word, it's lowercase.

Stepping other countries, he can't even hold his size except he starts out first.

> In other countries/languages, "I" isn't capitalized by itself.

Comment: For  _Only the guy at first place, may be as big as he is._ might mean  that capital **i** can be seen as a roman no 1 (**I**).

Comment: @Nappa Interesting interpretation. I personally like mine better, but we'll have to wait and see what OP says.

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps the answer is

> Antigua and Barbuda (whose Internet code is Ag)

As

> Others are Australia(Au)and Cuba+Senegal(Cu+Sn, representing Bronze).
>  Usually Silver medalist outsmarts others,except the Gold medalist.

Being small,

> Ag is the first one(and hence a smaller index, a kind of stretch here) compared to Au and Cu+Sn